# Check ArrayList content with Java stream

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Consider following ArrayList:

```
[0] => Person
[1] => User
[2] => Dummy
```

How can one with Java streams check if this arraylist contains any other objects than `Person` or `User` ?

So that I can make an if statement to return null if it contains **only** `Person` and `User`, or return the arraylist itself if it contains any other objects besides `Person` or `User` like so:

```
if( /*arrayList contains only Person and User*/ ) {
  return null;
}
else {
  //arrayList contains other objects besides Person and User
  return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: why not use `instanceof`?

Comment: Is this an `ArrayList<Object>` (or `ArrayList<?>`)? Why are you using raw types?

Comment: Yes, it is an arraylist of not specified object types

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `Person` and `User` are types, rather than specific objects, you can do something like this.

```
return list.stream()
           .filter(o -> !(o instanceof Person) && !(o instanceof User))
           .findAny()
           .isPresent() ? list : null;
```

Comment: OP hasn't specified that he is using Java8, so you should also provide a pre-Java8 solution ..

Comment: @hagrawal He specified he wanted to use streams.

Answer (score 11):

Alternative to Paul's answer (with the if-else in your question)

```
if (arrayList.stream().allMatch(o -> o instanceof Person || o instanceof User)) {
    return null;
} else {
    return arrayList;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this to my answer as it doesn't create a useless `Optional` object.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I would also expect `allMatch` by itself to be more efficient than `filter`. It will return early on the first mismatch which could be the first element. But it would be interesting to return an `Optional` of `List` instead of null or `List`

Comment: `filter().findAny()` will return early too. I agree that it's a bit odd to return either a `List` or `null`.

Comment: It's usually advised to return an empty list instead of `null`. I'd say that an `Optional<List>` is not much better than `null`, compared to an empty list.

Comment: Well, it’s not recommended to use things like `Optional<List<…>>`. Usually, you want to return either `Collections.emptyList()` or just a new list where all illegal items are removed. Returning `null` or an absent list is a rather unusual requirement, as it implies that the caller will have to perform a `null` check and thus conditionally not using the list reference, which is not simplifying the usage compared to just returning the `boolean` value of `allMatch`.

Answer (score 1):

Use filters

```
List<Object> objLst = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(new Object[] {new User(), new Person(), new Dummy() }));

return (objLst.stream()
    .filter(e -> !(e instanceof User || e instanceof Person))
    .limit(1)
    .count() > 0) ? null : objLst;
```

Comment: `.filter(…).count()>0` is potentially wasting resources counting items when the count is already greater than zero. `.filter(…).findAny().isPresent()` or even simpler `.anyMatch(…)` are better alternatives as they return immediately after *one* matching item has been encountered. If you want to keep your `count` based solution, you may improve it by using `.filter(…).limit(1).count()>0` as then, it will also stop on the first encountered item.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a solution which does not hard-code the list of classes using `ìnstanceof`, as in

```
    List<Class<?>> clist = Arrays.asList(Person.class, User.class);
    List<?> list = Arrays.asList(new Person(),new User(),new Dummy());

    List<?> result =  list.stream()
            .map(Object::getClass)
            .anyMatch(x ->
                    clist.stream().
                            noneMatch(c->c.isAssignableFrom(x)))
            ? list : null;
```